# How can I transform an image to group colors?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find anything without having a more descriptive name of the transformation.

I would like to apply a transform on either a PIL image or an array of floats that represent a black and white image. Ideally the transform would alter the image like this (sorry, made in paint with a track pad):

[image: Desired image transform]

I would consider it a bonus if it could preserve a black border around each color region, but that might be asking a lot depending on how the transform works. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See morphological operations on images https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html

Comment: section 3. Opening looks like it should do the trick. Submit as an answer and I'll mark it as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [morphological operation](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) on the image:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
img = cv.imread('img.png',0)

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
# Opening is erosion followed by dilation. It is useful in removing noise.
opening = cv.morphologyEx(img, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
```